# MySQL inserting timestamp value causes command to fail

Tags: mysql

I am having problems inserting into a timestamp field.

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `sponsorlog` (
  `updated` timestamp,
  `user` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `change` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the insert command:

```
insert into sponsorlog (user, company, change, updated) 
values ('attaskadmin@llts.com', '3M', 'Sponsor Jon Bove added', '2015-08-10 17:43:32');
```

And the error is the typical useless MySQL error. It seems to be pointing at the date/time value but I can't see anything wrong with it. Any ideas?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'change, updated) values ('attaskadmin@llts.com',
>   '3M', 'Sponsor Jon Bove added',' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

`change` is a reserved word and needs to be quoted. In MySQL the identifier quote character is the backtick: `

```
insert into sponsorlog (user, company, `change`, updated) 
values ('attaskadmin@llts.com', '3M', 'Sponsor Jon Bove added', '2015-08-10 17:43:32');
```

Also `user` is a non-reserved keyword, so to be consistent you might want to use quotes for all columns.

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word,
>   you must quote it whenever you refer to it

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)